# CKEditor won't link files (backed by rails, mongoid, paperclip, s3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ckeditor

I'm having issues with CKEditor. I can upload and insert pictures without issues, but when I try to do the same with files, the link to my file is set to something like `javascript:void(0)/*130*/`, with the number changing. This is happening on FF/Safari/Chrome.

My app runs on rails 3.1.3, using MongoDB/Mongoid as database/ODM, with paperclip for handling attachments and using S3 for hosting assets. When I explore my bucket I can see that the files are uploaded correctly, so the problem (probably) come from somewhere else. I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), and both the rc2 & the master branch doesn't fix that.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's been a while. I solved it by forking the gem (cf [ksol/ckeditor](https://github.com/ksol/ckeditor)), but the diff is too obfuscated to remember what was wrong. Hopefully the original gem is working now.